# How to "debounce" or clean up this logic signal

Tags: operational-amplifier

I may not have used the correct terminology with "debounce" as I'm aware this word is usually reserved for the noise created as the output of a physical button goes from low to high, so please forgive me but I wasn't sure the best way to describe the signal I have.

I'm making an audio sensing circuit which feeds the signal from an electret microphone (powered by 3.3V) into two op-amps (dual op amp LM358P): the first op amp amplifies the signal and is configured with negative feedback (inverting amp). The output is fed to the non-inverting input of a second op amp, and the inverting input is set using a voltage divider with variable resistor so that it can be calibrated to filter out power supply noise.

Here is my circuit:

[image]

If I click my finger, the output of the second op amp looks like this (see blue waveform):

[image]

I would like the output to be a single, clean pulse of e.g. 1 or 2 seconds long. Much like a PIR or similar sensor might give. It can reset after that period as long as no more audio is sensed. (The reason is that I'm sending it to the input pin of an ESP32 running Tasmota, with a switch input set, however the switch is not triggering.) The max voltage of the output I currently have is 2V, I believe this is because the LM358 will swing between VCC -1.5V and GND according to its data sheet. I think this should be fine to trigger the digital input of the ESP32, if not I could use a buffer.

**What type of circuit would I need to use to achieve this "time trigger" with minimum components?**

*Ideally I would use a single additional IC, or a couple of passives to achieve this.*

### Options considered

These are things I have guessed so far might work:

- I considered changing the second op amp into a multivibrator or even an integrator, although I don't fully understand if these will do what I want, also the former does add quite a lot of components.
- I also considered rectifying the wave before it enters the first amp (which currently cuts the bottom half of the wave off, I think this is because the rails are GND and 3.3V), then smoothing the input out with a capacitor.
- I also have 555 timers in my project box, but I don't know how to use them creatively to achieve what I want.

Are these ways viable? Is there a more simple or quick and dirty way?

I would appreciate any additional input if there's a trick I'm missing in the overall design.

Comment: `sending it to the input pin of an ESP32` ... use software to do the conversion

Comment: This would be good, except that I'm already running Tasmota on the ESP32 as it's a very good framework for all the other things I'm trying to do within my project. I could program an ATtiny to do it, but again want to avoid the complexity of that as I'm sure it can be done with components.

Comment: quick and dirty? As mentioned in the question, rectifying it is an option. A [peak detector](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/75p326/basic-peak-detector-01/), essentially. Perhaps on the output of the first op-amp ; adjust C1 and R1 to taste. // also do add hysteresis to the second amp, which you are using as a comparator

Comment: De-glitch may be the word you're looking for.  And the block to make that one pulse would be a re-triggerable monostable. (you can probably use a 555 for the job, after the second opamp, or software controlling a timer in the MPU.)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy It’s an LM358P with single supply between GND and 3.3.